# inline javascript stacktrace: better origin than @<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome extension. I need to append Javsacript as inline-script for content security purposes. The issue now is that, because script is inlined, the stacktrace shows @ as source, instead of the file name:

```
ReferenceError: asdf is not defined
fetchContactByEmail@<anonymous>:5439:1
```

I need to distinguish between the source of the caller in the stack trace, to tell if it's from my script. Is there a way to  tell the source of inline script?

(P.S. the problem I'm trying to solve is: there could be multiple extensions injecting script onto the same page, and they override Array.prototype methods. I want to set up a switch that checks if caller is my script, then execute my function; if caller is other extension's script, execute their function.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert the following snippet before or after your code:

```
//# sourceURL=name-of-script.js
```

Now, whenever your code throws an error, you will see "name-of-script.js" instead of `<anonymous>`. This feature is a part of Source maps, you can read more about this feature in the [Chrome devtools documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#source-maps).