# Making XHR requests in externally-loaded script (Gmail, Chrome 39.x, Content Security Policy)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gmail, content-security-policy

When an externally-loaded script (in a Chrome extension intended to augment Gmail) tries to make an XHR / AJAX request, it fails.

```
Refused to load the script 'https://<domain-path>.js?' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://talkgadget.google.com/ https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/installedApps/ https://www-gm-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/js/ https://docs.google.com/static/doclist/client/js/ https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/ https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/ https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/ https://apis.google.com/js/ https://clients1.google.com/complete/ https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/ https://ssl.gstatic.com/inputtools/js/ https://ssl.gstatic.com/cloudsearch/static/o/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/feedback/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/common_sharing/static/client/js/ https://www.gstatic.com/og/_/js/".
```

Because of this: http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/12/reject-unexpected-content-security.html

And from this question: [Gmail Content Security Policy on Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515117/gmail-content-security-policy-on-chrome-extensions)

The solution works for injecting an externally loaded script into the page. However, if that scripts makes XHR request, it's blocked the same way:

The workflow is:

- Extension launches for gmail.com, injecting a local file into head (preloader.js)
- Preloader loads an external Javascript file (actual-code.js) by injecting a  tag.
- Actual extension code tries to make an AJAX / XHR request and it's blocked by Gmail's CSP.

This doesn't seem to be solvable by updating the CSP in the extension, because those policies apply to content scripts, not any manually injected scripts.

Possible solution with drawbacks:
- Include the full code in the extension (harder to keep up to date, tied to extension releases)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The safe way would be to expose an "API" in your extension that your script can use.

Any script injected into the page with a tag exists in the page's execution context. However, it shares DOM with content scripts (that can use XHR as per your manifest).

You can raise a custom DOM event to ask your extension to perform XHR, and again to pass results back. Method is described here: [Gmail Extension, sendMessage to background from page context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838804/gmail-extension-sendmessage-to-background-from-page-context/25847017)

Comment: Not a bad one, and thought about it too, but it'd involve a good amount of refactoring for regular AJAX requests. While packing the full code within the extension as a content script has its drawbacks, it can be done to little to no modification from the original injected script.